# VBA changes complex formula

Tags: vba, excel, excel-formula, radio-button

I use code with Radio Button (see last code) to insert a new row into row 15, which pushes the old data down, and at the same time, copies the same formulas into row 15 that were once there (in row 15) before the button is clicked.

Once the button is clicked, I can enter 3 digit data into E15, then hit enter, and all formulas calculate across row15, based on what is entered in E15.

Now I love how the code performs, but for some reason, the formula in CG15 changes from

```
=IF(CF15=1,IF(CF15<>"",COUNTBLANK(INDEX(CF14:CF$14,MATCH(9.99999999999999E+307,CF14:CF$14)):CF15),""),"")
```

to

```
=IF(CF15=1,IF(CF15<>"",COUNTBLANK(INDEX(CF13:CF$14,MATCH(9.99999999999999E+307,CF13:CF$14)):CF15),""),"")
```

I can't figure out if the issue is in the code or formula in CG15
Here's a "test" file and below is the code

[test sheet](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1MVeTYZ_Vc4IKUnzIoSgVrVwDOYKN6aF_)

```
Sub AddNewDrawing()
'
' AddNewDrawing Macro
'

'
    Rows("15:15").Select
    Selection.Insert Shift:=xlDown, CopyOrigin:=xlFormatFromLeftOrAbove
    Range("A16:ua16").Select
    Selection.AutoFill Destination:=Range("A15:ua16"), Type:=xlFillDefault
    Range("A15:ua16").Select
    Range("E15").Select
    Selection.ClearContents
End Sub
```

This might be simple fix but I am stumped. I need the formula to remain the same and not change.

Here is more in depth information as to what each code does.
Column CF15 has this formula which returns 1 if the condition is met.

```
=IF(COUNTIF($AW16:$CC18,O15),1,IF(COUNTIF($AW16:$CC18,P15),1,IF(COUNTIF($AW16:$CC18,Q15),1,"")))
```

Column CG15 has this formula which counts skips(blank cells) between each of the 1's in column CF15.
Note: CG$14 has a permanent 0(zero) which acts as a place holder for the beginning of the count.

```
=IF(CF15=1,IF(CF15<>"",COUNTBLANK(INDEX(CF14:CF$14,MATCH(9.99999999999999E+307,CF14:CF$14)):CF15),""),"")
```

Thank you

Comment: I don't understand the `=IF(CF15=1,IF(CF15<>"",...` part. If CF15 is 1 then it cannot be "" so what is the second condition (`IF(CF15<>"", `) there for?

Comment: That may be a redundancy, but it is saying, if there is a 1 or anything else (less than or greater than blank "") (it doesn't have to be strictly 1) in CF15, then the coutntblank etc. part of the condition applies. perhaps the CF15<>"" part of the formula doesn't need to be there because at least for the calculation, there are only 1's in CF15. Either way it all works, but the inserting of the new row changes the CF14 to CF13, of which is what I don't want

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you insert a new row 15, the formula in CG15 is pushed down to CG16 and the relative addresses in the formula that refer to row 15 (e.g. CF15) become row 16 (e.g. CF16).

However, the relative addresses that are less than 15 like CF14 are unaffected by the row insertion. When you 'backfill' the formula from CG16 to CG15 they are all affected so CF14:CF$14 becomes CF13:CF$14 just as CF16 reverts back to the original CF15.

Change the formula to something that isn't affected by the relative difference between row insertion or backfill.

A row relative CF14 can be written in CG15 as,

```
index(CF:CF, row()-1)
```

So that makes your formula,

```
=IF(CF15=1, COUNTBLANK(INDEX(CF$14:index(CF:CF, row()-1), MATCH(1e99, CF$14:index(CF:CF, row()-1))):CF15), text(,))
```

Comment: Perfect Jeeped! TY